# How to change parameter in Observable (RxJs)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observers

I use HTTP provider in Angular 2 for data loading from API.

```
return this.http.post(url, urlSearchParams.toString(), {
        headers: this.getHttpHeaders()
    })
    .retryWhen((error) => {
        return this.handleRetryError(error);
    })
```

When there is no or old session I create new one in this.handleRetryError(error) and fill headers with it. (method getHttpHeaders() returns array with headers)

RetryWhen tries to do this post again, but there is unchanged (old) headers from first round.

**Is there any chance to change headers parameter for http.post from .readyWhen?**

Thank you very much for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the Observable and retry the resulting outer Observable so each time it executes again.

```
Observable.of(1).mergeMap(x=> {
  return this.http.get('data.json', this.configObject())
  .do(x => throw(x))
  .map(res=>res.json());
})
.retryWhen(e => e.delay(2000))
.subscribe();
```

for your code

```
return Observable.of(1).mergeMap(x => { 
    return this.http.post(url, urlSearchParams.toString(), {
      headers: this.getHttpHeaders()
    });
  })
  .retryWhen(e => this.handleRetryError(e))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The code here should put you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return Observable
    .defer(() => {
        this.http.post(url, urlSearchParams.toString(), {
            headers: this.getHttpHeaders()
        });
    })
    .retryWhen(errors => {
        this.handleRetryError(errors);
        return errors.delay(200)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly keep a reference to a headers variable outside that function, and then modify that variable inside the retryWhen function.

```
let headers = this.getHttpHeaders();

return this.http.post(url, urlSearchParams.toString(), {
    headers: headers
})
.retryWhen((error) => {
    headers.foo = "bar";

    return this.handleRetryError(error);
})
```